# Calculate the sum of values based on another column value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Sample dataframe

```
country   result    name  
  UK        3       created
  US        5       created
  UK        7       created
  India     4       completed
  India     6       created
  US        1       completed
```

Expected output

```
country   result    name  
  UK        3       created
  US        5       created
  UK        7       created
  India     4       completed
  India     6       created
  US        1       completed
  UK        10      pending       
  US        6       pending
  India     10      pending
```

I need to add the created and completed result on each country and it should have a name called "pending"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `groupby.sum` then `pd.concat`

```py
out = df.groupby('country', as_index=False)['result'].sum()
out['name'] = 'pending'
out = pd.concat([df, out], ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(out)

  country  result       name
0      UK       3    created
1      US       5    created
2      UK       7    created
3   India       4  completed
4   India       6    created
5      US       1  completed
6   India      10    pending
7      UK      10    pending
8      US       6    pending
```

Comment: I grouped by multiple columns but getting error "No axis named kpi_name for object type DataFrame" @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: Using like this,         out = df.groupby('id','kpi_name','org_country','month_start','month_end')['result'].sum()

Comment: @Mahilan If you want to group by multiple columns, you need wrap them into list.